# Using onBackPressed with visible Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an Activity that has a ViewPager inside of it holding 5 Fragments, and a bottom layout that has button that can switch between viewpager pages, however each one of this fragments can open a new fragment, I am replacing fragments in the MainActivity like the following:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

Fragment placeDetailsFragment = new PlaceDetailsFragment();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.right_in, R.anim.left_out, R.anim.left_in, R.anim.right_out).replace(rootViewID, placeDetailsFragment, fragmentTag.getKey()).addToBackStack(fragmentTag.getKey()).commit();
```

where rootViewId is the id of the root layout in the page.

the idea is that I can enter from page 1 in the viewpager to fragment 1 and from page 2 to fragment 2.. etc..

I want to be able when I press the hardware back button in fragment 1 to get back to page 1 and when I am in fragment 2 to get back to page 2 but the default onBackPressed behaviour is only popping the last fragment added to stack no matter which one is visible, so if I open fragment 1 then fragment 2 then I get back to page 1 from bottom views in the activity mentioned before and press back it's popping fragment 2 when it should pop fragment 1 because it is the currently visible.

how can i solve this?

Comment: You may need to basically implement the onBackStackChangedListener and add your own logic there.

Comment: @AndreiT can you please provide me with an example or a link?

Comment: Can you explain your situation better? It's hard to understand

Comment: @BlueMango sorry for my bad English, simply I want to pop the visible fragment from back stack not the last added one.

Comment: @EyadMhanna I posted an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Save the last Fragment:

```
Fragment lastFrag;
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

Fragment placeDetailsFragment = new PlaceDetailsFragment();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.right_in, R.anim.left_out, R.anim.left_in, R.anim.right_out).replace(rootViewID, placeDetailsFragment, fragmentTag.getKey()).addToBackStack(fragmentTag.getKey()).commit();

lastFrag = placeDetailsFragment;
```

Override onBackPressed to pop the saved Fragment:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.right_in, R.anim.left_out, R.anim.left_in, R.anim.right_out)
       .replace(rootViewID, lastFrag, fragmentTag.getKey()).addToBackStack(fragmentTag.getKey()).commit();

}
```

Notice *lastFrag* instead of *placeDetailsFragment* in .replace inside onBackPressed()

Comment: this is reimplementation of the default popBackStack behaviour that pops the last fragment added not the currently visible that I need :)